# django: how to display user logged-in in each template?

Tags: django, templates, view

I have following templates:

base.html & articles.html & article.html

base.html contains header:

```
<h6>User logged-in : {{full_name}}</h6>
```

articles.html and article.html extends base.html

In my django app "article" in views  I pass

```
args['full_name'] = request.user.username
```

and then:

```
return render_to_response('article.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I do the same for function articles. It allows me to pass variable to extended base.html header in articles.html and article.html

It means I need to do the same for def edit_article, for function create_article and I end with duplicating myself so I break basic django rule.

Is there any other better way to display who is logged in and use it to create separate views for each logged in user as below:

each user can see his own views, edit it, add new articles and give access to his views to the other users / user groups ?

?

Comment: https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian

Answer (score 6):

You can access *user* using (no needs pass it to context once more)

```
{{ request.user.username }}
```

Comment: I have just eddited and removed args['full_name'] = request.user.username from all article.views functions and left args['full_name'] = request.user.username in my main view for my base.html and it seems it works for all articles but if I create or edit or view article then the page does not show user logged in.

Comment: sorry it was typo ... request.user.username

Comment: you can always access request in your templates if you have  'django.template.context_processors.request' in context_processors (settings)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Comment: ok, it helps but I just need to have "context_instance=RequestContext(request)" in each function in return render_to_response

Comment: @BlueTomato you should use the `render` shortcut, not `render_to_response`, as that always uses RequestContext.

Comment: Thank you ! It solves my problem with multiple context_instance ! render is much better than render_to_response